# Get old version of a file in aws s3 in R?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, version

I need to retrieve a old version of a file based of version-id.
I have tried something like :

```
    is.saved <- aws.s3::save_object(file="C:/Desktop/myfile.txt", object="s3/path/file.txt", bucket="s3bucket", query=list('version-id' = '123')
```

The parameter 'version-id' is ignored and I always get the latest version.

Comment: Why are you calling `save_object` for retrieval?

Comment: there might be better functions that I am not aware of, but this one worked for me in order to save the s3 file locally.

Comment: Right, the question is why are you calling it to *retrieve* a version?